# Flutter the best way to compress image

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm try to compress image before upload to the storage using flutter image_picker package.
I found three ways to do it, but I'm not sure which way is the best.

1. using image_picker package's imageQuality params

[image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

2. using flutter_image_compress package

[flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

3. using flutter_native_image package

[flutter_native_image](https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image)

is there any difference between these options?

Appreciate any helps and explanation.

Comment: Image picker is quite faster than others.

Comment: image picker maybe faster, but it seems not compressed image size so much than others...

Comment: It should, Bcz lates image picker has more functionality compare to the older ones, You can pass max height and maxWidth and image Quality.

Comment: Remember, you can resize your image with 
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 1024, maxWidth: 1024);

Comment: Thanks for comments. I knew how to do it. I want to know which way is the best in terms of process speed and compress quality.

Answer (score 117):

Here's a breakdown of the potential solutions. The TLDR is that the flutter_image_compress package shrinks files much more than the ImagePicker class can itself.

**Image Picker**

As others have suggested, you can use the built in imaqeQuality property from ImagePicker to compress the image. This property takes a value between 0 and 100 and represents a percentage of the original image quality. The benefit to this approach is that it's built into the image_picker package and is therefore incredibly easy to use.

```
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,  
                imageQuality: 25,
    );

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

I did a little test to see how much various values effect the size of the image:

**100% Image Quality - 4.58MB**
[image]

**50% Image Quality - 3.58MB**
[image]

**25% Image Quality - 2.61MB**
[image]

**1% Image Quality - 2.12MB**
[image]

**0% Image Quality - 3.9MB**
[image]

In summary, you can reduce the file size of an image by more than half without much of a visible difference. Trying to force the image quality to 0% doesn't actually shrink the file size.

**flutter_image_compress**
The [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) package is fairly simple to use and it appears to be much better at actually reducing the file size.

```
Future<File> compressFile(File file) async {
  final filePath = file.absolute.path;

  // Create output file path
  // eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd_out.jpeg"
  final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
  final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
  final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";
  var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    file.absolute.path, outPath,
    quality: 5,
  );

  print(file.lengthSync());
  print(result.lengthSync());

  return result;
 }
```

I'll omit the images here because the all look the same:
**50% Image Quality - 590KB**
**25% Image Quality - 276KB**
**5% Image Quality - 211KB**

**flutter_native_image**
The [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) package is comparable to the flutter_image_compress package as far as file sizes go.

```
Future<File> compressFile(File file) async{
    File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(file.path,
        quality: 5,);
    return compressedFile;
  }
```

**50% Image Quality - 1.02MB**
**25% Image Quality - 309KB**
**5% Image Quality - 204KB**

I guess one of the benefits to this method is that you don't need to provide it with an output pathway for the compressed file.

Comment: can you please tell how did you calculate the image size in megabytes of the picked file?

Comment: You can take the files length in bytes and calculate in kilobytes or megabytes and so on.
Like this: 
file.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes -> file size in bytes
(file.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes) / 1024 -> file size in kilobyte
(file.readAsBytesSync().lengthInBytes) / 1024 / 1024 -> file size in megabyte

Comment: Thanks Joe! Good to add a function to delete the uncompressed file from cache or else it will have 2 files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137910/flutter-how-to-delete-a-file-inside-the-flutter-app-directory

Comment: thank you so much that was a good review. but I think the quality of the photo to be obvious it differs from one picture to another, so it  also depends on something else because I tried to set the  imageQuality: 5, and the quality was so bad

Comment: Can you please add info about the speed of each compressor?

Comment: `flutter_native_image` is now deprecated, and `flutter_image_compress` can only "compress" JPEG to JPEG or PNG to PNG -- the input format has to be the same size as the output format. Maybe try `flutter_image_utilities`?

Comment: flutter_image_compress only support mobile, not desktop, note

Answer (score 20):

**image picker**

with image picker you can set image quality easily and efficiently just as shown below

```
File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

image quality is in percentage % 100 being the highest

Comment: Thanks for answering. I knew how to do it. I want to know which way is the best in terms of process speed and compress quality.

Comment: i would go with image_picker as its supported by the flutter team and you can rely on it in the long term

Comment: Appreciate to your thought and help!

Comment: is there something similar to this for ```pickVideo```?

Comment: With image picker apparently of today no..you can check other ways to compress video

Answer (score 14):

I've built an app which uses three packages to compress an image file: [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress), [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image), and [flutter_luban](https://github.com/crazecoder/flutter_luban). After comparing these packages, I can say `flutter_image_compress` is the best tool to compress images so far.

My app was inspired by @Joe_Muller's response, and the source code is [here](https://github.com/warcayac/compressors_comparison)

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

An image compress package like Luban for Dart. This library has no system platform constraints.

[plugin](https://github.com/crazecoder/flutter_luban)

Answer (score 1):

**Import in pubspec.yaml**

> flutter_image_compress

**Image compress function**

```
    import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';
    
    void compressWithImageCompress(
        {required String path, required double quality}) async {
      
      final response = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
        path,
        minWidth: 320,
        minHeight: 240,
        quality: quality.truncate(),
      );
    
    }
    
   
    //Compress image from camera 

    Future<File> compressFile({required File? file}) async {
      final filePath = file!.path;
    
      // Create output file path
      // eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd_out.jpeg"
      final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(RegExp(r'.jp'));
      final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
      final outPath = '${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}';
      var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        file.path,
        outPath,
        quality: 80,
      );
      return result!;
    }
```

**use this where you compress your image file**

```
   var pickedfile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      //you can use ImageCourse.camera for Camera capture

      if (pickedfile != null) {
        pickedImage.value = File(pickedfile.path);

        // Image compress function
        final img = await compressFile(file: pickedImage.value);

        // Load compress image
        pickedImage.value = img;
        imagefiles.add(pickedImage.value!);
      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found the following method to be highly effective for image compression, using the **[Image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image)**:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

File compressAndResizeImage(File file) {
  img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to have the longer side be 800 pixels
  int width;
  int height;

  if (image!.width > image.height) {
    width = 800;
    height = (image.height / image.width * 800).round();
  } else {
    height = 800;
    width = (image.width / image.height * 800).round();
  }

  img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(image, width: width, height: height);

  // Compress the image with JPEG format
  List<int> compressedBytes =
      img.encodeJpg(resizedImage, quality: 85); // Adjust quality as needed

  // Save the compressed image to a file
  File compressedFile = File(file.path.replaceFirst('.jpg', '_compressed.jpg'));
  compressedFile.writeAsBytesSync(compressedBytes);

  return compressedFile;
}
```

This code efficiently resizes and compresses images. It resizes images to have a maximum dimension of 800 pixels while preserving the aspect ratio. Then, it compresses the image using JPEG format, allowing for adjustable quality to suit your needs.

**Source: [Medium Article - Image Resizing & Compression in Flutter: A WhatsApp-Inspired Approach](https://medium.com/@milanbhikadiya/image-resizing-compression-in-flutter-a-whatsapp-inspired-approach-19ff88b38436)**

Comment: how did you go from "without relying on any third-party packages" to "using the **[Image package][1]**" in the span of 6 minutes?

Comment: @starball  My bad, I came across this Stack Overflow Q&A that didn't quite provide the solution. Then, I stumbled upon a Medium article where I found a code snippet that seemed to work for my case. It wasn't until later that I realized the code relied on the image package, which I mistakenly thought was built into Flutter, but which I already had installed.