# How to permanent delete Image File from device gallery (local storage) using image path in Flutter dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I found one answer to delete file using dart.io package

```
      var _image = io.File(path);
      var value3 = await _image.delete();
```

but its not deleting a file from local storage both android and IOS. please suggest any package or solution.

This is the Full Code, first i am saving the image to gallery, then i convert the uri to file and showing the image into ImageWidget but when i try to use file.delete(); to delete image, image still showing into the gallery but it removed from ImageWidget.

```
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';
  void takePhoto() async {
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

try {
  _picker
      .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
      .then((recordedImage) async {
    if (recordedImage != null) {
      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(recordedImage.path,
          isReturnPathOfIOS: true);
      final path =
          result['filePath'].toString().replaceAll(RegExp('file://'), '');
      print("save path ${result} ${path}");

      var file = await toFile(path);
      setState(() {
        fileImage = file;
        fileImage!.delete();
      });
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("${e}");
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by "local storage"? `File.delete` works fine, all you need is to pass **right** filename path when creating `File` object

Comment: Hello, Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143775/11893675

Comment: @pskink by local storage i mean device storage and File.delete is not deleting the file from gallery

Comment: @ParthMandalia this is not an answer to my question, I want to delete image file from device storage

Comment: @pskink i have updated the question for better understanding

Comment: so is the file deleted or not? tried to verify that with, for example `adb shell ls -l path_to_your_file`?

Comment: @pskink i am getting this `/data/data/com.gicproject.kic_inhouse_app/files/uri_to_file/1669292052473.jpg: Permission denied`

Comment: @pskink. i come to this conclusion that file.delete() is working but image_gallery_saver is not returning the actual file path, but the returned path is working fine to show image when i try to put a hardcoded text the file has been deleted using file.delete() my usecase is want to create new image save into gallery and delete it, i am stuck into delete path