# Delete file permanantly from list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I list all pdf files from storage and now I want to delete multi-files in my flutter list . as well as from the device file manager. I am using this function but when I delete and restart the app the file comes again

This is the function I'm using to delete the list:

```
void deleteItems() {
    var list = myMultiSelectController.selectedIndexes;
    list.sort((b, a) => a.compareTo(b));
    list.forEach((element) {
      files.removeAt(element);
    });
    setState(() {
      myMultiSelectController.set(files.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`files.removeAt(element);` Just removes file from the list. You need to actually delete file from device.

eg

```
 Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    print('path ${path}');
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> deleteFile() async {
        try {
          final file = await _localFile;

          await file.delete();
        } catch (e) {
          return 0;
        }
      }
```

See [more here from SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143775/10409567)