# How to take a picture straight to a variable without saving it

Tags: flutter, camera

Using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package with the function `cameraController.takePicture()` I can take pictures, get `XFile` and convert them to `Uint8List`.

My use case includes taking a lot of pictures and sending them.
Currently because of `takePicture` function each picture is getting saved to **cache** and my app can get to storage of 500+mb.

Is there a way to take pictures without also saving them to cache?, just have it on a variable and dart garbage collector will remove it as soon as it stops being used like a normal variable.

Comment: tried https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/startImageStream.html?

Comment: Yes but didn't manage to make it work. But this is probably the best solution.

Comment: Currently in my project i handle this situation by deleting the image after i use it using "delete" function in XFile. For the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143775/12566347

Comment: This is also the next plan I had XD. I will use the code you linked for now. Thanks for the help.
Also I have opened a issue for that so Flutter team can help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137889