# Image Compression in flutter of a Image File

Tags: android, ios, flutter, imagepicker, flutter-image

```
Future<void> saveLocalStorage(File image) async {

// get file format of the image
String fileFormat = image.path.split('.').last; // jpg

// get path for applications directory
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

// January 1st, 1970 at 00:00:00 UTC is referred to as the Unix epoch.
int time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

// saving image into applications document directory
image.copy('${directory.path}/$time.$fileFormat');
}
```

This is the code that I am currently using to save an image File. But before saving, I wish to compress the Image. I found a solution using the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package
but its documentation itself says that it isn't fast enough so I don't prefer using it. Another solution was using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) whose example code is:

```
ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile compressedImage = await imagePicker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  imageQuality: 85,
);
```

I tried using the same example but the source attribute doesn't File as its value so I am unable to do the compression.
Please suggest some solution to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library : [Flutter Image Compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

Compresses image as native plugin (Obj-C/Kotlin)

or unknown reasons, image compression in Dart language is not efficient, even in release version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Narendra_Nath, ur answer was quite useful.
Later, I came across this solution, [Flutter the best way to compress image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800808/flutter-the-best-way-to-compress-image) it explained 3 packages, one of which was the [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) package, it was suitable for my case but I preferred using the [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) package as it had easy to understand syntax.
 The ***flutter_image_compress*** package has a required attribute i.e. output path which was to be determined forehand, it felt quite overwhelming for me so, I used the [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) package.

Check the solution mentioned earlier in this answer to know more about those 3 packages.

Comment: will do thanks.:)