# is there a proper way to compress image

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

#This is the function from which i select multiple image from gallery and add it to my own list that is imageFileList

```
  final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  List<File> imageFileList=[];
  String images;
  void selectImages() async {
    List<XFile> selectedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage(imageQuality:5);
    if (selectedImages != null) {
      for(int i=0;i<selectedImages.length;i++) {
        imageFileList.add(File(selectedImages[i].path));
      }
```

#everything works fine but the problem is that i want to compress. Meaning the image which i pick from gallery first i want to get its size and if its size is greater than 40mb or 20mb or 15mb.. then i want to reduce to 5 mb or even to kb by keeping the quality of image and if the image is already in kb i dont want to compress it. i want to achieve it something like this but i am little confused on how to achieve that and add it to my imageFileList. Need some help thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter the best way to compress image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800808/flutter-the-best-way-to-compress-image)

Comment: This is a duplicate please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800808/flutter-the-best-way-to-compress-image

Comment: i dont think that helped i already tried that if the image is high quality it is good but if the image is of low quality then image becomes unredable

Comment: you can check the size or quality before and then make the code adapting dynamically to this values. Also resizing could help with your problem

Comment: Also this Link provides some good details: https://it-qa.com/how-do-i-compress-an-image-without-losing-quality-flutter/

In the end nobody will write the code for you but point you in the right direction

Comment: i know no body will write code for me and i didnt ask anyone to write code for me also just asking how to achieve it and thansk for the response